# T-SQL Slowly Changing Dimension - Multiple Updates, Single Action Output?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scd

I've implemented four SCDs for the warehouse I'm working on and they're working a treat. Hopefully I've understood SCD methods correctly and assuming I have, I now have a bit of an issue I'd like help with.

The issue is that there are fields that can be updated without needing to make a new dimension as they're not time-relevant. So in the MERGE statement I'd like to have two statements:

```sql
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.HashBytes_Value <> src.HashBytes_Value
THEN 
   UPDATE Row_Expiry_Details
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.HashBytes_Value = src.HashBytes_Value
THEN
   UPDATE Columns_That_Are_Not_SCD_Relevant
etc..
```

I'm not sure how to add a second WHEN MATCHED to the query.

Here is an example of the code that runs fine now, but doesn't do what I want.

```sql
-- Created temp tables for example
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #StagingTable
CREATE TABLE #StagingTable
(
    id INT,   
    name VARCHAR(20),
    team VARCHAR(20),
    preferences VARCHAR(50),
    hashbytes_Value VARBINARY(20)
)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PresTable

CREATE TABLE #PresTable
(
    dim_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    team VARCHAR(20),   
    preferences VARCHAR(50),
    hashbytes_Value VARBINARY(20),
    row_Current_ind BIT DEFAULT(1),
    row_effective_date DATETIME2 DEFAULT(SYSDATETIME()),
    row_expiry_date DATETIME2 DEFAULT(SYSDATETIME())
)

-- Load Staging
insert into #StagingTable (id, name, team, preferences, hashbytes_Value)
select id = 1, name = 'archibald', team = 'team 1', preferences = 'Throwaway String', hashbytes_value = hashbytes('sha1', (select team = 'team 1', name = 'archibald' for xml raw))
union select id = 2, name = 'dave',  team = 'team 1', preferences = 'Throwaway String', hashbytes_value = hashbytes('sha1', (select team = 'team 1', name = 'dave' for xml raw))
union select id = 3, name = 'peter', team = 'team 2', preferences = 'Throwaway String', hashbytes_value = hashbytes('sha1', (select team = 'team 2', name = 'peter' for xml raw))
union select id = 4, name = 'roger', team = 'team 2', preferences = 'Throwaway String', hashbytes_value = hashbytes('sha1', (select team = 'team 2', name = 'roger' for xml raw))

-- scd merge 
insert into #PresTable (id, name, team, preferences, hashbytes_Value)
select id, name, team, preferences, hashbytes_Value 
from
(
merge into #PresTable as tgt
using
(
select
    id
    ,name
    ,team
    ,preferences
    ,hashbytes_value
from
    #StagingTable
) as src
-- alias
(id, name, team, preferences, hashbytes_Value)
on src.id = tgt.id
-- must be most recent row
and tgt.row_current_ind = 1
when matched
and tgt.hashbytes_value <> src.hashbytes_value
then
update 
set 
    tgt.row_current_ind = 0
    ,row_expiry_date = sysdatetime()
when not matched
then 
insert
(
    id
    ,name
    ,team
    ,preferences
    ,hashbytes_Value
)
values
(
    src.id
    ,src.name
    ,src.team
    ,src.preferences
    ,src.hashbytes_value
)
output
    $action
    ,src.id
    ,src.name
    ,src.team
    ,src.preferences
    ,src.hashbytes_value
)
as changes
(
    action
    ,id
    ,name
    ,team
    ,preferences
    ,hashbytes_Value
) where action = 'update'

truncate table #StagingTable
insert into #StagingTable (id, name, team, preferences, hashbytes_Value)
select id = 1, name = 'archibald', team = 'team 1', preferences = 'Updated Throwaway String', hashbytes_value = hashbytes('sha1', (select team = 'team 1', name = 'archibald' for xml raw))
union select id = 3, name = 'peter', team = 'team 1', preferences = 'Updated Throwaway String',  hashbytes_value = hashbytes('sha1', (select team = 'team 1', name = 'peter' for xml raw))
union select id = 5, name = 'russell', team = 'team 2', preferences = 'Updated Throwaway String', hashbytes_value = hashbytes('sha1', (select team = 'team 2', name = 'roger' for xml raw))


-- scd merge 
insert into #PresTable (id, name, team, preferences, hashbytes_Value)
select id, name, team, preferences, hashbytes_Value 
from
(
merge into #PresTable as tgt
using
(
select
    id
    ,name
    ,team
    ,preferences
    ,hashbytes_value
from
    #StagingTable
) as src
-- alias
(id, name, team, preferences, hashbytes_Value)
on src.id = tgt.id
-- must be most recent row
and tgt.row_current_ind = 1
when matched
and tgt.hashbytes_value <> src.hashbytes_value
then
update 
set 
    tgt.row_current_ind = 0
    ,row_expiry_date = sysdatetime()
when not matched
then 
insert
(
    id
    ,name
    ,team
    ,preferences
    ,hashbytes_Value
)
values
(
    src.id
    ,src.name
    ,src.team
    ,src.preferences
    ,src.hashbytes_value
)
output
    $action
    ,src.id
    ,src.name
    ,src.team
    ,src.preferences
    ,src.hashbytes_value
)
as changes
(
    action
    ,id
    ,name
    ,team
    ,preferences
    ,hashbytes_Value
) where action = 'update'




select * from #PresTable
```

That final output should be as you see it BUT preferences should be 'Updated Throwaway String' where id = 1.

Is this possible in the same merge statement? Or do I need an update before/after I run the merge statement?

Post was edited by somebody, but this is the example I want to see in the end:

```sql
UPDATE TGT
SET
    TGT.preferences = SRC.preferences
FROM 
    #PresTable TGT
INNER JOIN 
    #StagingTable SRC
    ON SRC.id = TGT.id
WHERE 1=1
    AND TGT.hashbytes_Value = SRC.hashbytes_Value

select * from #PresTable
```

Thank you.

Comment: Apologies if the formatting is poor, I threw this together to give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) docs says (emphasis mine):

> **WHEN MATCHED THEN merge_matched**
>
> Specifies that all rows of *target_table, which match the rows
>   returned by  ON , and satisfy
>   any additional search condition, are either updated or deleted
>   according to the  clause.
>
> The MERGE statement can have, at most, two WHEN MATCHED clauses. If
>   two clauses are specified, the first clause must be accompanied by an
>   AND  clause. For any given row, the second WHEN
>   MATCHED clause is only applied if the first isn't. **If there are two
>   WHEN MATCHED clauses, one must specify an UPDATE action and one must
>   specify a DELETE action**. When UPDATE is specified in the
>    clause, and more than one row of 
>   matches a row in target_table based on , SQL
>   Server returns an error. The MERGE statement can't update the same row
>   more than once, or update and delete the same row.

So you can't issue 2 different `UPDATE` on the match condition. What you can do is use 1 `UPDATE` and conditionally update the columns to the new value or their current value if your condition doesn't apply:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE TableName SET
    Column1 = CASE WHEN tgt.HashBytes_Value <> src.HashBytes_Value THEN UpdatedColumn1 ELSE Column1 END,
    Column2 = CASE WHEN tgt.HashBytes_Value <> src.HashBytes_Value THEN UpdatedColumn2 ELSE Column2 END,
    Column3 = CASE WHEN tgt.HashBytes_Value <> src.HashBytes_Value THEN Column3 ELSE UpdatedColumn3 END
```

Keep in mind that triggers will be called for rows that might not actually get "updated".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This sort of works for me, the issue is that I OUTPUT the UPDATE step to INSERT a new row to the SCD - I'm not sure how I can filter out the values where HashBytes_Value is equal.

Comment: You can't. Either insert and delete it afterwards (which sucks) or remove the merge statement and do the operations in multiple statements, with a transaction. When merges start to get big or complex, I always find it better to split them.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll add an update statement after the merge and wrap both in a transaction. Question though, if I wrap it in a transaction will I stop the PowerBI instance from being able to read the table at all with a tranaction lock until commited?

Comment: Plus one for "do the operations in multiple statements with a transaction." I've shied away from `MERGE` since the first time I read [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) from Mr. Bertrand.